# Dynamically change text color, depending on the background, while the user scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a floating, fixed skip-link navigation that overlays on the right side of the page with no background. Basically just floating bubbles and text. As the user scrolls, I'd like to change the color of the navigation text depending on if the background is light or dark.

I've found a few things about setting the color based on background images, but the navigation won't always be floating over an image. Does anyone have any experience with this? I tried to find some examples, but haven't really come across anything, so maybe its just not possible right now.

Here's a fiddle with the basic idea of what I want.
https://jsfiddle.net/y867dL46/

HTML

```
<div class="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li class="bubble">
            <div class="label">Link1</div>
        </li>
        <li class="bubble">
            <div class="label">Link2</div>
        </li>
        <li class="bubble">
            <div class="label">Link3</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="section1"></div>
<div class="section2"></div>
<div class="section3"></div>
```

CSS

```
.section1, .section3 {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}

.section2 {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    right: 30px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.navbar ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.bubble {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 1000px;
}

.label {
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
}
```

So I'd like the color of the navbar to change to white when it scrolls over the black section, and then back to black when it scrolls over the white sections.

Comment: Create a fiddle so we can see what it is you want to do. Or at least include some code

Comment: Okay I added a fiddle and the code.

Comment: Possible, but very consuming! This would be the steps: **(1)** Find current scroll-position. **(2)** Find which section is at that scroll-pos. **(3)** Check that section's background-color. **(4)** Determine whether the navbar should be black or white, and change it's color accordingly... Steps *1,3,4* are relatively easy, but **step 2 is very consuming!** Normally you would check *for one element* what it's scroll-pos is. But since you need to find what section is at your scroll-pos, you would have to compare the scroll-pos of EVERY SECTION on the page, on EVERY PIXEL YOU SCROLL!